# Spark mllib Word2vec BLAS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec, blas

I want to generate words vector representation using Word2Vec Model with spark mllib on data set of 2 Go. My code to achieve this is as follows:

```
val testDF = spark.read.json("test.json").cache()
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.{Word2Vec, Word2VecModel}
val word2vec = new Word2Vec()
val testText = testDF.select("text").map(line => line.mkString.split(" ").toSeq).toJavaRDD
val model = word2vec.fit(testText)
model.save(sc, ".")
```

When I run this chunk on spark-shell, it takes long time in the call to the **.fit** method, i gave the executor the number of 6, and a 6g to my driver-memory, but it still takes too long, I also have this warning:

```
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
```

After some research the warning was maybe due to spark not being able to use native implementations of these classes, so I builded a fat jar with this dependency:

```
 libraryDependencies += "com.github.fommil.netlib" % "all" % "1.1.2" pomOnly()
```

And ran the spark-shell with --jars pointing to it. 
But I still got the same warning, and computations still takes too long.Has anyone faced the same issue ?

Comment: Check documentation at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html#dependencies  to understand why you get the warning and how to install blas to accelerate your script.